# How to retrieve value of <p> tag in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

i am trying to get the value of my p tag in order to send it as data to the next page. The p tag is labelled in the code.

html:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <ion-title name="title">Job Requests</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <div class="filter">
        <button class="islandwide" ion-button large>Islandwide</button>
        <button class="nearby" ion-button large>Nearby</button>
    </div>

    <ion-list>
        <ion-card *ngFor="let user of request | async" class="job">
            <button ion-item (click)="goToJobDetails()" class="info">
                <ion-avatar class="avatar" item-start>
                    <img src="../assets/icon/user_male-512.png">
                </ion-avatar>
                <h2 class="name">{{user.regdetails.username}}</h2>
                <p text-wrap class="address">
                    <ion-icon name="compass"></ion-icon> {{user.regdetails.address}}</p>
                <p ng-model="userkey">{{user.$key}}</p>
                <---- trying to pass this over </button>

        </ion-card>

    </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

ts:

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { JobdetailsPage } from '../jobdetails/jobdetails';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 
'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
selector: 'page-request',
templateUrl: 'request.html'
})


export class RequestPage {

request: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
userkey: any;

constructor(private ef: ElementRef,public navCtrl: NavController, angFire: 
AngularFireDatabase) {
this.request = angFire.list('/request');
}

goToJobDetails(){
let data = {
  key: this.userkey
};
console.log(data);
this.navCtrl.push(JobdetailsPage, data);
}

}
```

trying to get value of {{user.$key}}

and send it over to next page.

Page to receive this data

ts

```
  ionViewDidLoad(){
  console.log(this.navParams.get('key'));
  }
```

Comment: You cannot use ng-model with p tag

Comment: Tried using value but does not work either.

Comment: How should i do it?

Comment: try to use document.getElementById()

Comment: You can pass the key in your click function like this (click)="goToJobDetails(user.$key) and access it in your js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your button click event you can pass the value like this,

```
<button ion-item (click)="goToJobDetails(user.$key)" class="info">
```

in your ts,

```
goToJobDetails(data){      
   console.log(data);
   this.navCtrl.push(JobdetailsPage, {'param1':data});
}
```

to retrieve it from another page you can use navParams,

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
      console.log(this.navParams.get('param1'));
   }
```

hope that helps

Comment: How do i retrieve that data and console log it?

Comment: that is what this line(goToJobDetails(data){   console.log(data); }) does

Comment: It sends the data over but how do i retrieve/call it?